# creating an SQL Table

Tags: java, sql

How would I go about creating an SQL file that stores name, age in a log table. I have very very basic knowledge of SQL but I do not have enough to do what I need to do in Java. I looked for a few tutorials but have found nothing on what I wish to do.

Please note I do not want to connect to an actual database but create a file that can be imported into a SQL database

Comment: Can you provide some more information

Comment: What do you need java for if you aren't connecting to a db?

Comment: My program is running in Java and I need it to output the information to a SQl file so that it can be used later by a database

Answer (score 4):

You need to [create a database table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) and then connect to the data base and use the [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) command to add rows of data to the table.

I think this question is a little too broad for stack overflow, and you should do more research. Check out the links above, and the [`java.sql`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) code as well as general research on [relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that I do not want to connect to an actual database but
>   create a file that can be imported into a SQL database

Then write Java program to write your data in CSV format. Comma-separated text files can be imported into SQL-based databases.

Comment: Although true, this is not best practice and I don't think OP knows enough to know that.

Comment: @PRNDL Development Studios - I didn't imply that OP's Java process should do the importing. He was asking how to create a file that *can be imported*.  I quoted that part and based my answer on it.